# Accessing Spoitify API with Rspotify to obtain genre information for multiple artisrts

Tags: r, for-loop, user-defined-functions, spotify

I am using RStudio 3.4.4 on a windows 10 machine.

I have got a vector of artist names and I am trying to get genre information for them all on spotify. I have successfully set up the API and the RSpotify package is working as expected.

I am trying to build up to create a function but I am failing pretty early on.

So far i have the following but it is returning unexpected results

```
    len <- nrow(Artist_Nam)
    artist_info <- character(artist)      

  for(i in 1:len){
ifelse(nrow(searchArtist(Artist_Nam$ArtistName[i], token = keys))>=1,       
  artist_info[i] <- searchArtist(Artist_Nam$ArtistName[i], token = keys)$genres[1],
  artist_info[i] <- "")

    }
    artist_info
```

I was expecting this to return a list of genres, and artists where there is not a match on spotify I would have an empty entry ""

Instead what is returned is a list and entries are populated with genres and on inspection these genres are correct and there are "" where there is no match however, something odd happens from [73] on wards (I have over 3,000 artists), the list now only returns "". 
despite when i actually look into this using the searchArtist() manually there are matches.

I wonder if anyone has any suggestions or has experienced anything like this before?

Comment: Is there a limit to how many requests you can make through the API per minute or something like that. Adding a small delay within the looo might help if thats the case.

Comment: @Dason That was exactly the issue! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a rate limit to the number of requests you can make a minute and you may just be hitting that limit.  Adding a small delay with `Sys.sleep()` within your loop to prevent you from hitting their API too hard to be throttled.